# How to use simplified select box IF statements PHP

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I have a trip status page and I want to output the status of the trip.

I'm storing numeric values in the Database on creation of the trip.

**Status values:**

- 0 = On Time
- 1 = On Hold
- 2 = Delayed
- 3 = Completed
- 4 = Canceled

**This is my current working IF Statement:** *Just want to simplify it*

```
<select name="status">
    <option value="{{ $destination->status }}" selected>
        @if($destination->status == 0)
            On Time
        @elseif($destination->status == 1)
            On Hold
        @elseif($destination->status == 2)
             Delayed
        @elseif($destination->status == 3)
            Completed
        @elseif($destination->status == 4)
            Canceled
        @endif
     </option>
@foreach ($status as $key => $value)
<option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}
</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

**For simple YES or NO IF Statements I can do this:**

`$destination->private` = 0 for No & 1 for Yes

```
<option value="{{ $destination->private }}" selected>{{ $destination->private ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</option>
```

> How can I take the Simple Yes or No Logic and apply it to my larger
>   select box If Statement?

Comment: Take a look at [LaravelCollective HTML](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) - it can do this elegantly & perhaps make your life a lot easier.

Comment: So a different question, what is the point of outputting this in a `<select>` element? Are you giving the user the option to change this status? In that case, you'd output 5 options (using a `@for($i ...)` loop), check the value of `$i` and output the correct label, and cross-reference `$destination->status` vs `$i` to set one of the options as `selected`. If you're not doing that, then this falls under bad-ui; providing a `<select>` element that doesn't allow selection seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Hey @TimLewis, This is for updating the Trip status in my admin area. Not for public use.

Comment: Question still stands; doesn't matter who the user is (admin vs end user), if you've got a select that doesn't allow you to select anything, then it doesn't make much sense :)

Comment: @Tim sorry I didn't add this because it wasn't relevant to my question. The user can make selections.... `@foreach ($status as $key => $value)<option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option> @endforeach`

Comment: That looks pretty relevant to me; if `$key` is 0 through 4, and value is a `string` containing the "On Time", "On Hold", etc. then there is no need for the `@if()` statement at all. You would simply do `<option value="{{ $key }}" {{ $destination->status == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>` to cross-reference and set one of them as selected by default.

Comment: @Tim you're right, that was completely relevant I added it to my question.

Comment: So you want to have 1 `<option>` element at the top of the list that shows the current status? I think you're overthinking this; just remove the first `<option>` and use the code you have in conjunction with the `{{ $destination->status == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}`; the displayed option will be the current status, and allow for selection without duplicating `<option>` elements.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Show the current status and allow the user to change it if an update is needed.

Comment: Haha I guessed as much. I'll write an answer to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this block of code, the first `<option>` is completely superfluous; it's duplicating an option below it, can should be removed entirely in favour of cross-referencing `$destination->status` with `$key` (0 through 4, based on the array):

```
<select name="status">
  <option value="{{ $destination->status }}" selected>
    @if($destination->status == 0)
    On Time
    @elseif($destination->status == 1)
    On Hold
    @elseif($destination->status == 2)
    Delayed
    @elseif($destination->status == 3)
    Completed
    @elseif($destination->status == 4)
    Canceled
    @endif
  </option>
  @foreach ($status as $key => $value)
  <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

This can simply be replaced with:

```
// $status = ["On Time", "On Hold", "Delayed", "Completed", "Cancelled"];
<select name="status">
  @foreach ($status as $key => $value)
  <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ $destination->status == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $value }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

As long as `$status` is an array containing the various labels ("On Time", "On Hold", etc.) this code will display the current status as the default selected option, without duplicating options and allowing select normally.

Comment: Thanks for helping me work through this. Thats almost my exact array: `$status = ['On Time', 'On Hold', 'Delayed', 'Completed', 'Canceled' ];` in my controller.
This was well explained and worked great. So much cleaner too! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! This is similar to a lot of the approaches I have to do, but I save my array in a translation file (`resources/lang/en/status.php` in this example), then simply do  `@foreach(__("status") AS $key => $value) ... @endforeach`

Answer (score 2):

You can't simplify a conditional with 5 separate if/else's into a ternary that is remotely legible.

First, I would not tie your view to the numbers that represent your statuses. Consider some methods on your `$destination` class. For example:

```
protected const ON_TIME = 1;

public function isOnTime(): bool
{
    return $this->status === self::ON_TIME;
}
```

Use these in your view

```
@if ($destination->isOnTime())
  On Time
@else ...
```

While this doesn't simplify your conditional, it is much cleaner than needing to keep track of what integer value corresponds to which status.

You might also consider a model decorator like [laracasts/presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter).

Push that conditional logic into a presenter class.

```
use Laracasts\Presenter\Presenter;

class DestinationPresenter extends Presenter {

    public function status(): string
    {
        if ($this->isOnTime()) {
            return 'On Time';
        }

        if ($this->isOnHold()) {
          return 'On Hold';
        }
    }

}
```

Then in your view you can really simplify things:

```
{{ $destination->present()->status }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice tips here. I will refer to this when I go back and refactor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as it should match your if statements to the [ternary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) form (although somewhat confusing):

`$destination->status % 2 == 0 ? ($destination->status == 0 ? 'On Time' : ($destination->status == 2 ? 'Delayed' : 'Cancelled')) : ($destination->status == 1 ? 'On Hold' : 'Completed');`

Comment: From that same page: "_It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions._" And yes, looks somewhat confusing ;)

Comment: Pretty sure stacking of ternary statements is a matter of opinion; some will argue to never do it, others will argue that as long as you can read it, and it works, then why not? I'm of the opinion that anything above 2 statements should probably be a `switch` or `if ... elseif ...` block, but yeah.

Comment: This works, but yeah, Really confusing on whats happening at first glance. Thanks for showing me another way.

Answer (score 0):

`@switch` is made for this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="status" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option value="{{ $destination->status }}" selected>
        @switch ($destination->status)
            @case(0)
                On Time
                @break
            @case(1)
                On Hold
                @break
            @case(2)
                 Delayed
                @break
            @case(3)
                Completed
                @break
            @case(4)
                Canceled
        @endswitch
     </option>
</select>
```